# Replacing "System Menu Extention"

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, window-manager, shell-extension

> SysMenuExt is an Extension to the Windows System Menu, the menu that
>   appears when you right-click a program on the task bar.
>
> It adds "Always On Top", "Minimize To Tray" and "Transparency" sub
>   menus to all top level system menus.

I used it in the past (up to Windows 7) and I tried to install it on my Windows 10 system, but turns out it doesn't work properly because the last release of this software debuted almost 11 years ago, according to "System Menu Extention"'s page on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sysmenuext/) [sic].

The technical reason should be that the hook mechanism used to add the menu items is outdated.

So I am looking for a replacement that works with Windows 10...

I would like to include a screenshot of the program but when run on windows 10 the menu items never appear, so I will include a normal screenshot edited with the expected elements in red.

Pardon the Italian localization.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I am using [**Dexpot**](http://dexpot.de/) right now, but it lacks some features & usability, since it mainly is a virtual desktop manager.

Notably the menu items are grouped in a sub menu, requiring an additional click to get things done with the system menu.

Also, "Minimize to Tray" does not "Minimize to Tray" when clicked, but instead sets up the window so that if I click the system-provided minimize button it will minimize to the notification area. The fix for this is to configure it to send windows to notification area by right clicking the regular minimize button.